# Three.js: Project Objects onto Plane Perpendicular to Camera

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, geometry

I have a simple scene in Three with some planes. Right now on click the planes move to random positions.

After a click, I'd like instead to move the planes into a new grid perpendicular to the camera, such that the projected grid's x and y axes are parallel with the screen's x and y axes.

Here's the scene:

```js
// generate a scene object
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

// generate a camera
var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.01, 10000);

// position the camera
camera.position.set(51.389, -451.056, 839.455);
var rotObjectMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
var q = {_x: 0.0184, _y: -0.2122, _z: 0.9770, _w: -0.0081};
rotObjectMatrix.makeRotationFromQuaternion(q);
camera.quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix(rotObjectMatrix);
camera.up.set(0.00806, -0.91008, -0.41432);

// generate a renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio); // <3 retina
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); // canvas size
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// generate controls
var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.target.set(19.053, -111.316, 93.996);

// generate some lights
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xeeeeee);
scene.add(ambientLight);

// render loop
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  controls.update();
};

// draw a grid
var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000);
grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
grid.material.transparent = true;
grid.rotation.x = -Math.PI;
scene.add(grid);

// draw some
planes = [];
for (var i=0; i<2**10; i++) {
  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 20, 20, 32 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
    {color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
  var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  var x = ((i % 2**5) * 40) - (2**5 * 40)/2;
  var z = (Math.floor(i/2**5) * 40) - (2**5 * 40)/2;
  plane.position.set(x, 0, z);
  scene.add(plane);
  planes.push(plane);
}

// transition the planes on body click
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function() {
  planes.forEach(function(plane) {
    // placeholder
    plane.position.set(
      Math.random() * 500 - (Math.random() * 500)/2,
      0,
      Math.random() * 500 - (Math.random() * 500)/2,
    )
  })
})

render();
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/97/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js'></script>
```

Using the following comes close, but doesn't tilt the planes such that they're perpendicular to the camera:

```
planes.forEach(function(plane) {
  // close to projection discussed above...
  plane.position.set(
    plane.position.x,
    plane.position.z,
    0,
  )
})
```

Does anyone know how to achieve the projection described above? Any suggestions others can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at some OpenGL tutorial. You will learn about transformations using 4x4 matrices. Setting your camera requires position, direction of view and up-vector. This can be done with [LookAt matrix](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml). Combine this matrix with a perspective projection matrix (or an orthogonal one) and you've almost done.

Comment: Thanks @Ripi2, would you be able to show an example? I'm reading about on geometric topics at the moment, but haven't seen how to accomplish this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a shortcut, but it'll help you avoid a lot of math calculations: Just group your planes into a [`Group`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Group) and then use `Group.lookAt(camera.position)` to point them all in unison towards the camera.

```js
// generate a scene object
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

// generate a camera
var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.01, 10000);

// position the camera
camera.position.set(51.389, -451.056, 839.455);
var rotObjectMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
var q = {_x: 0.0184, _y: -0.2122, _z: 0.9770, _w: -0.0081};
rotObjectMatrix.makeRotationFromQuaternion(q);
camera.quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix(rotObjectMatrix);

// Not sure why you're changing camera's up axis, but this will
// need to be duplicated on planeGroup;
camera.up.set(0.00806, -0.91008, -0.41432);

// generate a renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio); // <3 retina
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); // canvas size
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// generate controls
var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// If you change the pos where the camera is looking at,
// you'll need to place planeGroup at this position.
controls.target.set(19.053, -111.316, 93.996);

// generate some lights
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xeeeeee);
scene.add(ambientLight);

// render loop
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  controls.update();
};

// draw a grid
var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000);
grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
grid.material.transparent = true;
grid.rotation.x = -Math.PI;
scene.add(grid);

// draw some
planes = [];
var planeGroup = new THREE.Group();

for (var i=0; i<2**10; i++) {
  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 20, 20, 32 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
    {color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
  var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  var x = ((i % 2**5) * 40) - (2**5 * 40)/2;
  var y = (Math.floor(i/2**5) * 40) - (2**5 * 40)/2;

  // Setting x,y instead of x,z
  plane.position.set(x, y, 0);
  planeGroup.add(plane);
  planes.push(plane);
}
scene.add(planeGroup);

// Copying camera.up and controls.target from above
planeGroup.up.copy(camera.up);
planeGroup.position.copy(controls.target);
planeGroup.lookAt(camera.position);

// transition the planes on body click
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function() {
  planes.forEach(function(plane) {
    // placeholder
    plane.position.set(
      Math.random() * 500 - (Math.random() * 500)/2,
      0,
      Math.random() * 500 - (Math.random() * 500)/2,
    )
  })
})

render();
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/97/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js'></script>
```

Then, if you want to randomize the plane's positions, you can still do that, but all you have to worry about afterward is to return them to their original `x,y,0` positions, and they'll automatically line up "looking at" the camera.

**EDIT:** I had to copy the changes you made to `camera.up` and `controls.target` for this to work. If you change these 2 attributes, you'll need to copy them to `planeGroup` for this approach to work.

[Here's the doc on the .lookAt() method](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt)

Comment: Thanks @Marquizzo. I'm afraid I didn't make my goals clear though. Inside the onclick callback, I want to position all planes, statically, such that they form a grid, and the x and y axes of that grid are parallel with the screen's x and y axes. This snippet seems to position the planes in such a way that they move to face the camera, which I'd like to avoid, and this snippet also doesn't make the x and y axes of the grid parallel to the screen's x and y axes. Do you know how to accomplish this intended layout?

Comment: Hmm... I'm having a hard time understanding how the grid looking at the camera doesn't make it parallel to the screen's x,y axes. Maybe if you drew a quick diagram illustrating the desired result?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm after this projection here: https://imgur.com/a/uL3YsPn The original grid is still present in the screen (it has a vanishing point and is projected), but the images after click form a grid that fills the screen and has x, y axes parallel with the screen's x, y axes. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you mean. My version is showing some odd z-rotation that doesn't align perfectly. Either the cam or group's y-up axis is tilted. I'll have to re-think my answer.

Comment: @duhaime Ok, I edited my answer to accommodate for the changes you made to `camera.up` and `controls.target` parameters.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much @Marquizzo. This is very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Threejs has built in class for that.

[THREE.Sprite](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=spr#api/en/objects/Sprite)

Just use this. It is built for your purpose.